# are all devices compatible with my x86 APK?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, device

It seems unity now support x86 as well. I exported very simple scene with x86 and then armv7 to my asus memopad tablet. Result: armv7 gives me about 54 fps (too bad) and x86 60 fps. Here is the question: are all devices compatible with my x86 APK? Because my tablet can run both.

Is there anything related to IOS I should consider with this issue in the future?

Answer (score 0):

No all devices not compatible with my x86 APK.
if you want to check just check Build.CPU_ABI, if it will contains x86 then it is 
compatible other wise not.
such as in moto devices not compatible and with asus its compatible.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI